# Safari not opened in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, safari

I installed Safari-4. 3 with Quicktime in Ubuntu but it will not open.

When I try to open it Safari shows as starting in the taskbar but then it goes away without actually starting.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question confuses me. How are you even running Safari in Linux?

Under Windows emulation like so?

- http://lifehacker.com/370635/run-safari-inside-ubuntu
- http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-safari-on-ubuntu7.10-with-playonlinux

That can't be.. stable..

Comment: I don't get it. Did it work for him or not? His question was extremely vague.